# home page nonexistent in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, black-screen-of-death

Logging in to the laptop is fine but once in I only get a blqck screen with a cursor. I can access task mqnager through ctrl alt del and file explore through that and everything else seems to be working except my home screen

Comment: did you recently upgrade? I had a system with some issues with a user account post upgrade that did that. Ended up blowing away that specific account from a second account and reinstalling

Comment: No I upgraded when It first came out but the system did update directly before the problem

Answer (score 0):

Next time you start off your PC, just press F8 continuously until you see a whole list of options for starting Windows 10. Choose Last Known Good Configuration (you'll have to boot the same way every time you start off your PC). If that doesn't work, try to recall what was the last time you used windows perfectly. Then go to system restore in the setings and set the restore time to that date or before that (you can lose a few programs like that, though.)

Comment: Where do I find sysyem restore?

Comment: @baileystone What did your research tell you? [Recovery options in Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options)

Comment: In the settings panel. I don't know much about windows 10 as I have never used it, but these are common things found from Windows 95.